# jQuery IF/ELSE based on URI in WordPress not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, uri, addclass

I've got a website, http://mxaward.org, and it's a WordPress site. For some reason, the first page and the 'Artikelen' page do not have the current-menu-item class which indicates that you are on a certain page. It does work for the 'Partners' and 'Contact' pages.

I decided to make a jQuery xcript in the header that would check the URI and if it was `== "/"`, it would select the first menu item and it would `addClass('current-menu-item')`. If `URI == "/artikelen/"`, it would select the second menu item and add the class.

I put this in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var uri = "<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>";
   if (uri == "/"){
     jQuery('ul.mx-nav li:first').addClass('current-menu-item');
   } else {};
   if (uri == "/artikelen/"){
     jQuery('ul.mx-nav li:nth-child(2)').addClass('current-menu-item');
   } else{}
});
</script>
```

The weird thing now is that the index-part works beautifully (first menu item is selected and the class is added), but the 'artikelen' part doesn't.

I used to have an `if(){} else if(){} else {}` instead of `if(){}else` twice, but it had thesame effect.

I `echo`'d the URI, the uri is fine. I tried `li:eq(1)` and several selector variants. I've even switched the two if/elses to see if it would only pick the first or second if/else.

I'm completely lost, does anyone have a solution for me?

Thanks,
-Sean

Comment: Look at your console output in element inspector. The issue is not with the script, your supersized function is throwing an error so your script isn't even running. Maybe a jQuery conflict?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about fixing that, or even finding out if/what exactly conflicts. What I find particularly odd is that the code for the index works flawlessly, where the code for the second page doesn't work. I did get the code for the second page to work on the first page though.. It's like the second page won't allow any jQuery or something.

How would I go about fixing this issue?